# change save button text of a node to submit

Tags: nodes

I am using drupal 7.10 I have a content type in which i want to change the save button text to submit.I tried various posts in this forum to no avail.i need help on this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the complete `$form['actions']['submit']` array the Node module uses for the form.

```
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#access' => variable_get('node_preview_' . $type, DRUPAL_OPTIONAL) != DRUPAL_REQUIRED || (!form_get_errors() && isset($form_state['node_preview'])),
      '#value' => t('SaveTest'),
      '#weight' => 5,
      '#submit' => array('node_form_submit'),
   );
```

You need to hook into the node form.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['#node']) && $form_id == YOUR_NODE_TYPE . '_node_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('YOUR_NEW_VALUE'),
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This should be pretty easy using a hook_form_alter, replace CONTENTTYPE with the machine readable name of your content type and MYMODULE, remember to always use underscores ("_") too.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   if ($form_id == 'CONTENTTYPE_node_form') {
         $form['buttons']['submit']['#value'] = "submit";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Due the mistake I did, I'm going to change my answer from:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'CONTENT_TYPE_node_form') {
     $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
              '#value' => t('your_value'),
     );
  }
}
```

or via jQuery...

```
$('#form_id').val('your value');
```

to:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['#node']) && $form_id == CONTENT_TYPE . '_node_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('your_value'),
  }
}
```

or via jQuery

```
$('#form_id #input_id').val('your value');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out [Node buttons edit](https://drupal.org/project/node_buttons_edit) module.

> This is a simple little module that allows one to change the text on
>   the 'Save', 'Preview' and 'Delete' buttons on a node form.